# remote file access in node or an alternative for samba server

Tags: node.js, express

I want to access a remote system folder and have to perform read and delete operations to that particular folder.

I have username as well as password.

The remote location has IP of 192.168.1.***
with username : root and password : password

ex. Alternative for samba server in linux.
Note: It isnt a webserver so no url available

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to execute a remote command on that system.  I would recommend using ssh to do so and sshpass to handle the password negotiations.  Not the most secure, but the simplest way to do something quickly.  You can install sshpass (in Ubuntu) with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Then, in your program, use exec to kick off the remote command:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var CommandArguments = [
        'sshpass',                  //specify sshpass as command we are issuing
        '-p',                       //tells sshpass next parm is password
        'password',                 //the password for plc
        'ssh',                      //command to issue command to PLC over network
        '-o',                       //option flag
        'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', //tell ssh not to care about RSA key checking
        'root@192.168.1.**',        //specify username and IP
        'ls',                       //command to issue
        '/home'                     //parameters for command to issue
    ];

//kick off install process
var child = exec(CommandArguments.join(" "), function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log("error: ", error);
    console.log("stdout: ", stdout);
    console.log("stderr: ", stderr);
    });
```

The code above logs into the server 192.168.1.** as root using 'password' as the password and lists the directory /home on the remote server.

You just need to replace the 'ls' and subsequent elements in the array with your specific command and desired command parameters.  From here you should be able to do anything you could do in a terminal on the remote system.